# Flutter - Error while adding Launcher icon -A dependency may only have one source

Tags: flutter

I tried to add launcher icon to my project , but I am getting this error ,

Error on line 86, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.

I have created assets folder/icons/launcher_png.Then I have added below line in the pubspec.yaml, but getting error while running pub get 
"Error on line 86, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source." . Actually , I need to generate launcher icon for both Android and IOS.

Here is my screenshot,

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have added flutter_icons under dev_dependencies. It should be at same level of dev_dependencies not under it.

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "icons/icon.png"
```